# Are there natural enzymes that catalyze different reactions under different conditions?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

Are there natural enzymes that catalyze different reactions under different conditions? For example an enzyme undergoes a conformational change under certain pH and starts catalysing a different reaction.

Comment: see "moonlighting proteins", for example: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstb.2016.0523